# css transform:translate breaking layout in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transforms

having a hard time figuring out how to fix my layout issue in IE.

For centering my site title in my header I am using css transform.

```
.herobox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

This works fine in chrome, firefox, mobile, etc...

But when i view the site in IE, it causes a huge horizontal scroll bar that i cant seem to get rid of.

[image]

It seems IE thinks that the element is still not moved to the center of the screen and is still on the right side of the page.

If i remove just the the transform element from the css, i get this.

```
.herobox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[image]

When I remove the herobox element all together, It removes my site title and all that fun stuff, and the horizontal scroll bar and white space on the right side of the screen goes away.

[image]

I'm stumped.

**UPDATE**
**My current header css styles.**

```
/*------------------------------------*
#HEADER-STYLES
\*------------------------------------*/

header {
    height: 75vh;
    color: #fff;
    /* NEEDED TO POSITION ELEMENTS INSIDE HEADER */
    position: relative;
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(cssimages/header-footer/headerbkrnd3-xsm-min.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

I had to change temporarily to using margin: 0 auto and top:25% until i can figure out why css transform is not working in ie 11. It wouldn't bother me as much if it didnt work before IE 9, but many people still use IE11.

Comment: What version of IE please?

Comment: IE version is IE 11. The site in question is showmethosegifts.com

Comment: Try adding to the <header> position: relative

Comment: I updated my original question.